# Boot from initrd on libvirt vm (UEFI + syslinux)

Tags: initramfs, kernel-panic

I'm building a simple Linux system, and I've created a kernel and an initrd using compressed cpio. My goal is to boot directly into the initrd shell instead of pivoting to another storage.

Trying to boot using the `-kernel` and `-initrd` option on QEMU I get a successful shell but booting from a libvirt VM running Coreboot UEFI and a syslinux bootloader I cannot successfully boot.

I'm trying to boot with `/vmlinuz initrd=/initrd root=/dev/ram0 rw` which per the kernel documentation will use `/dev/ram0` to create a ramdisk and uncompress my initrd into it.

But when the kernel tries to mount ram0 it gets a

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "ram0" or unknown-block(1,0): error -30
```

I looked for error -30 without success, also the kernel hints that all 16 ramdisks are available but the kernel cannot use them.

Both `BLK_DEV_INITRD` and `BLK_DEV_RAM` are enabled